# How to trigger a jQuery autocomplete plugin using Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, tampermonkey

I'm trying to Tampermonkey a website that has auto-complete input text-boxes.

When a user types something in one of these text-boxes it triggers a jQuery search widget, using [jqueryui 1.8.2](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js).

I couldn't find a solution to my problem at https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/.

What I am trying to do is take a string from my userscript and insert it in one of the text-boxes.  Then I want to trigger the jQuery search automatically.  I can get the string into the textbox easily.

```
$('#website_Textbox').val('My String');
```

Once I put the string in I can't figure out how to trigger the jquery search.

I've tried `.change()`, `.trigger('change')` I've also tried to focus the text-box and clicking in the text-box and nothing works.

The only way to get it to search is with a keypress.  I've tried creating an event `keypress` and that didn't work either.  I cant send actual key-presses with javascript.  Anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [JQUI's "search" method<sup>Doc</sup>](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search).  EG:

```
$('#website_Textbox').val ('My String').autocomplete ("search", "My String");
```

**Live Demo:**

```js
var wordList = [
    "The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog.",
    "Several", "fabulous", "dixieland", "jazz", "groups", "played", "with", "quick", "tempo.",
];
$("#zWords").autocomplete ( {source: wordList} );

$("button").click ( function () {
    $("#zWords").val ("er").autocomplete ("search", "er");
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p><button>jump-start autocomplete</button></p>
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="zWords">Words: </label><input id="zWords">
</div>
```

Or in a *Tampermonkey* script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _autostart JQUI autocomplete value
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @grant    none
// ==/UserScript==

$('#website_Textbox').val ('My String').autocomplete ("search", "My String");
```

Note that in some instances, use of `@grant` other than `none` *might* require script injection.

Comment: I figured this out, finally.  The solution posted above does work, but only if you copy over the native function that instantiated the autocomplete widget on to the Tampermonkey script.  Thanks for the help @Brock Adams